# WinUI 3: Is there a way to force a canvas to be updated after clearing it in a event

Tags: c++, wpf, xaml, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I use this to clear the canvas.

```cpp
mainCanvas().Children().Clear();
```

The UI will surely change after the event, but I would like to take a screenshot just after the canvas being cleared. I've tried various methods but always get a screenshot of uncleared canvas.
At last, I separated the actions into different events to achieve it, but I still wonder how to do this in a single event.

This is very much the same situation as for WPF. [Clearing canvas has a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406457/clearing-canvas-has-a-delay)

Comment: Do you have a minimal full reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried to run `Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync(s => { do screenshot });` from some object (like the window)

Comment: Sadly, the DispatcherQueue in WinUI3 seems to remove all asynchronous APIs. There should be some extensions in CommunityToolkit, but it only supports C# and has not been updated for quite some time.

Comment: Have you tried `DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(DispatcherQueuePriority.Low, () => { do screenshot});` ?

Answer (score 0):

In both WPF and WinUI the UI is rendered in another thread, not the "UI" thread of your application.

One approach would be to subscribe to [CompositionTarget.Rendered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.compositiontarget.rendered?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2) event just before you call `mainCanvas().Children().Clear();`, then save the image and immediately unsubscribe from the event handler.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to register a delegate with winrt::auto_revoke, but it seemed to be revoked too early. I will try more then.

Comment: Since rendering is done in two separate threads, it will always be a game with no clean winner.  Changes in the rendering can come from many sources, including animations or transition effects.  Therefore, there is never a reliable way to tell when exactly your canvas is empty.  You may try with setting and monitoring a flag (set it after "Clear" and reset it after taking a screenshot), but this is still kinda flaky.

Comment: I agree with you that it's difficult to know whether the canvas is exactly empty on screen.